# Which one is correct: Attached file includes or The attached file includes?

Tags: grammar

Please advise:

Should I use "Attached file includes" or "The attached file includes?"

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: Dropping the article is fine in abbreviated styles, but not in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

As Edwin notes in his comment, it is common to drop the article in emails. How common? To answer that, we'd need access to a large number of emails in an easily searchable format. The [Enron Corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_Corpus) gives us just such a dataset. There are 5,413 references to "[attached file](http://archive.enron.email/?q=%22attached%20file%22&sort=_score_desc)," only 797 of which refer to "[the attached file](http://archive.enron.email/?q=%22the%20attached%20file%22&sort=_score_desc)."

Comment: But for context, reading a sentence 'Attached file includes the spreadsheet of...' sounds a little off and 'the' would sound much more natural in informal or formal situations.